# Socket Error in Python: BlockingIOError: [Errno 11] Resource Temporarily Unavailable

Tags: python, sockets

So I'm having a problem with the Python Socket module that has completely stumped me.  I've searched the internet for answers but nothing seems to work for my case.  The problem is this.  I'm trying to send data from one a raspberry pi, or a seperate process on my main computer, to my main computer using sockets.  When I attempt to do this, I get the error as seen in the title.  However, I also have a website that can use the exact same code through an ajax call and it works fine!  I really cannot find any difference between the code, it just simply won't work when I execute the exact same code from my Pi or the Python shell.

Server code:

```
self.ServerSocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
#Bind socket to local host and port
#pdb.set_trace()
try:
    self.ServerSocket.bind((HOST, self.portnum)) # HOST is "", portnum is 8001
except socket.error as msg:
    print ("Bind failed. Error Code : ", str(msg))
    sys.exit()

    #Start listening on socket
    while (self.bServerShutdown==False):

        # wait to get packet
        while True:
            # addr is a tupl, so ip = addr[0] port = addr[1]
            # Shortened method: data, (ip, port) =  self.ServerSocket.recvfrom(1024)
            data, addr = self.ServerSocket.recvfrom(1024) # buffer size is 1024 bytes

            ip=addr[0]
            port=addr[1]
```

Ajax code (Which works when being called form the website):

```
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

server_address = (ipAddress, 8001) # ipAddress = '127.0.0.1' Since site is running on localhost

try:
    sent = sock.sendto(Command.encode('utf-8'), server_address)
    sock.setblocking(0)
    ready = select.select([sock], [], [], 5)
    if ready[0]:
        data = sock.recv(4096)
        #logging.info("received '%s'".format(data))
    else:
        #logging.info("Timeout")
        data=b'Service Manager Timeout. Is it running?\r\n'
except:
    continue
```

'
Code I'm using in the shell (Does not work):

```
import socket
import select
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
server_address = ('127.0.0.1', 8001)
sent = sock.sendto('test command'.encode('utf-8'), server_address)
sock.setblocking(0)
ready = select.select([sock], [], [], 5)
if ready[0]:
    data = sock.recv(4096)
else:
    data ='timeout'
```

So to recap, my server code is running.  When I navigate to localhost, which is setup to monitor my computer data, everything is good.  It makes the ajax call as seen in the second code snippet and data is returned just fine.  When I attempt the third code snippet from a Python shell, it returns the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
BlockingIOError: [Errno 11] Resource temporarily unavailable
```

So what the heck is going on?  Am I missing something really simple or is it something more complicated?  Any help would be appreciated.